# How to bind the dynamic data in the resource file for localization using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, localization

I need to make my app to support for multiple languages. So I had created *resource* files and also binded the strings.

If some strings are coming as dynamic so how do i bind those values in resource files because those values are coming while app is running. Before start I can't hard code those values in resource files.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i bind those values in resource files because those values are
>   coming while app is running.

I don't think you can bind values in resource files dynamically. You have to put strings in your fresh string resource file in advance, while the strings are generated dynamically and we don't know what they are.

If you want to achieve this:

1. maybe you can find and add a `translator` in your app and translate the string you generated.(**Just my thinking**, I haven't tried this way so far)
2. You could send the `string` and `language type` to your server side to get localizable string in different Language. Ask your server side to translate the string for you.